# Updating my regex to include dots and hyphens

Tags: javascript, regex, string, match, regular-language

My regex code `[A-Z]{1,}\d{3,}\w?` works fine returning strings like CX3623, M3326, Y2362 but I also want to be able to return strings which are in the following format:

```
YH321-2
V2021/V2022
1.2A-2351
YGH256-4268
```

What should I add to the regex?

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/MjPkFh/2

Comment: Correct me if I get it wrong, but the third example would never match?
I mean, it starts with a non-character.
For the rest, perhaps `[A-Z]{1,}\d{3,}[\d-/]*\w?`?
Otherwise, could you provide a list of text and what you expect to match and not to match?
I use https://regexr.com/ to explore regular expressions.

Comment: Looking at your original issue you could suffice with `[A-Z]+\d{3,}`. The `\w?` part seems redundant. Considering your new task.... These strings all seem quite different. What is the rule on which your strings are build?

Comment: It depends on the accepted characters and format, but perhaps `^[A-Z]*\d+(?:\.\d+)?[A-Z]*(?:[\/-][A-Z]*\d+)?$` https://regex101.com/r/GP6jQA/1

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/MjPkFh/2 It seems the 2222-0221 is not included and YH321-2 is also missing -2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first part, you could match the different formats using an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html).

You could make the second part optional using an optional non capturing group `(?:...)?` and match either `/` or `-` optionally followed by chars A-Z and 1+ digits.

```
\b(?:[A-Z]+ )?(?:[A-Z]*\d{3,}|\d+(?:\.\d+)?[A-Z]+)(?:[\/-][A-Z]*\d+)?\b
```

**Explanation**

- `\b` Word boundary
- `(?:[A-Z]+ )?` Optionally match 1+ chars A-Z followed by a space
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `[A-Z]*\d{3,}` Match 0+ times A-Z and 3 or more digits
  - `|` Or
  - `\d+(?:\.\d+)?[A-Z]+` Match 1+ digits with an optional decimal part and 1+ times A-Z
- `)` Close group
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `[\/-][A-Z]*\d+` Match either `/` or `-`, 0+ times A-Z and 1+ digits
- `)?` Close group and make optional
- `\b` Word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oMWalz/1/)

Comment: I have a string simmilar to "This is the same problem as resolved in COB 4000-9876". Is it possible to match only the identifier COB 4000-9876 out of the entire sentence? Currently the regex you posted doesn't match anything from my string

Comment: @shAkur That is due to the anchors `^` and `$`. I have updated it to use word boundaries `\b` Do you mean like this? `\b(?:[A-Z]+ )?(?:[A-Z]+\d+|\d+(?:\.\d+)?[A-Z]*)(?:[\/-][A-Z]*\d+)?\b` https://regex101.com/r/gwt8F3/1

Comment: Not really... that includes additional characters which I don't want. See https://regex101.com/r/ipuBTH/1 from there I only want to get TT3641

Comment: @shAkur Perhaps like this `\b(?:[A-Z]+ )?(?:[A-Z]*\d{3,}|\d+(?:\.\d+)?[A-Z]+)(?:[\/-][A-Z]*\d+)?\b`  https://regex101.com/r/oMWalz/1

Comment: This is an improvement, indeed. Except CPCR K494S, all the other identifiers were matched by this pattern. Is it too difficult to make it include the above identifier too? What about excluding suffix identifiers like CPCR in CPCR M3333 or TOR in TOR 1.2A-0876?

Comment: @shAkur You could add matching 0+ chars A-Z after the first alternative https://regex101.com/r/b0Lh3v/1 If you want to exclude the suffixes you could matched them and capture what follows in a capturing group. https://regex101.com/r/19nDsR/1